# What exactly does "Kofia" hat description mean?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

> first post between 12/26 and 1/1

Does that mean your very first post as a user should be made in those days?

Or that you should be the first user to post any post on a site starting 12/26?

Or something else?

The first option seems somewhat more likely but I'm not sure I'm parsing the description right.

Comment: kofia mean cap or hat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I understand it, it's your first post on a specific Stack Exchange site, which has to take place in those days.

Last year's Winter Bash also had a hat for the first post on a SE site, though there was no time frame then.

Comment: Yup. Last year hat hunting got me to post [this](http://pets.stackexchange.com/a/1725), giving me two hats in one shot. (first post and getting a bounty) :D

Comment: This is correct. In fact it's exactly the same code as last year, just using different dates.